# Qt/Qml - Press n hold the space bar - use your iphone space bar like a mouse

Tags: ios, qt, qml

Is it possible to get such cursor control in QML TextArea?

[image]

for example, a video on this topic
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XRUCnZFv9Ro

Answer (score 0):

Because Qt now encourages you to use QtQuick 2.x controls instead of QtQuick 1.x controls interactions need to be recreated in the Qt environment, and you can no longer rely on the OS to do this for you. Unfortunately, the user interaction you describe would take some effort to recreate.

To start, the following code only does the first part: intercepts the long press of a space. The second part had not been implemented, i.e. the handling of mouse drag:

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls

Page {
    property bool spaceDown: false

    Item {
        width: parent.width
        height: frame.height

        Frame {
            id: frame
            width: parent.width
            opacity: holdArea.focus ? 0.2 : 1.0
            TextEdit {
                id: textEdit
                width: parent.width
                Keys.onPressed: {
                    if (event.key === Qt.Key_Space) {
                        if (spaceDown) {
                            holdArea.forceActiveFocus();
                        } else {
                            spaceDown = true;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        Item {
            id: holdArea
            focus: true
            Keys.onReleased: {
                spaceDown = false;
                textEdit.forceActiveFocus();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can [try the first part here](https://stephenquan.github.io/qmlonline/?zcode=AAADmXichVI9b4MwEN39K25MFivtSIWqqG2kqkvSdq9cuAQrgJF9JEUV%2F702AQKhwBss%2Bd59v5NJpjTBjna5DI5M9r78SaWkVWwY24oDwi8Di0yrDDUV8K1UDCYTAT6rc%2BrBXsQGWeXzSpjU7g5nGVLkQSY0psSrX8tFKA8R2WgtEuSXH2vZjbN2MjnIsPbuWadqOCjbqKTCg0jF4Vqj4HsV5AYeYcXvwYM7vur5f%2BIPvYSSboo3DVBND8i5PhzesDBcpVuNxqBNNixRldnDAk8uyxEL8H3f6sJt6NeH2%2FlyJKqJbIWZcnTo7EMHuA5InnDjVrNYPowGloBW7JnMbQvgA%2BkcJ9L9ywytfcv1V14v5ub0HJxezZQ9oroAr%2BqtZ6%2F1eccYxYhA3dmqwx8O15zI7GK7c1zekv0B%2BFnccA%3D%3D)

Comment: Does this native iOS functionality work with Controls 1?

Comment: I cannot properly advise because I cannot build Controls 1 for an iOS to try. But, for you, if you are able to, simply put any Text input control, say, `TextEdit { }` but have it at Controls 1 *should* turn on standard iOS functionality such as that space-hold navigating. But, there are many plusses and minuses on Controls 1 control so your mileage will vary.

Comment: Please do report this if it has regressed: bugreports.qt.io